# Two hover states for a single class

Tags: html, css

I've got a common button set in my css. Also 've got a hover set to it.

```
.myBtn {
    background-color: #f60;
    border: none;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.myBtn:hover {
     background-color: #fff;
}
```

`.myBtn` is mostly on a black background, so the button is visible on hover state. But when `.myBtn` is on a white background, the button disappears because `.myBtn` hover color and the page background colour are the same.

My question is it possible to use `.myBtn` for all buttons create 2 different hover states?

e.g.:

```
.myBtn:hover1 {
     background-color: #fff;
}
.myBtn:hover2 {
     background-color: #000;
}
```

Comment: Nope, you'll have to use javascript/jquery for that.

Comment: Just use the parent as selector. .black-background .myBtn:hover {} and .white-brackground .myBtn:hover {}. Or use default on white and when the parent gets black specify otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, two hovers on one class won't work. Also when you declare two after each other, the stylesheet will be read cascade, so only the last will apply.

A possible solution would be to add an extra class.

```
.myBtn {
    background-color: #f60;
    border: none;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.myBtn:hover {
     background-color: #fff;
}
.myBtn.onWhite:hover {
     background-color: #000;
}
```

Then you'll only need to add an extra class on the buttons on a light background `<button class="myBtn onWhite">`.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to create 2 hover effects for a same class. You can either use a different class and provide hover to that or use jQuery to provide that effect.

Answer (score 0):

In what way do you change the background color? By hard coding your background-color? Or it's already written in two classes that when you trigger something, the html code will change the class name and thus the background?
If it's hard code I'm afraid you have to hard code the Btn class as well. But if it's triggered by something you can have another Btn class name and will be triggered together with background color.